# jQuery - add class to selected/checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I need to do something rather basic and check whether a checkbox has been `checked` and if it has been a class should be added to it so I can apply a few styles.

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]">User1
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]">User2
</form>
```

Problem is I don't know how to find out whether a checkbox has been checked within jQuery.

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="chk[]"]:checked').length > 0;
if (atLeastOneIsChecked) {
  $('tr > td').addClass('colorify');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cc1Lv6sw/)

Comment: Your code is correct, you just need to run it in the `.change()` handler of the checkboxes, not when the page loads.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Could you please take a look at the jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the code in the `.change` or `.click` handler for the checkbox. You can then use `this.checked` to test whether that checkbox is checked. Then you use DOM traversal functions to find the `td` elements in that row and apply the class.

```
$('input[name="checkbox[]"]').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').toggleClass('colorify', this.checked);
});
```

I've used `toggleClass` so that the class will be removed if there aren't any checked boxes.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/cc1Lv6sw/11/)

Comment: This applies the style to all rows. I need to apply it only to those that have been checked.

Comment: If that's what you wanted, why do you only test whether at least one is checked?

Comment: One more question. How do I save the changes and the addition of the class? Like using a button.

Comment: Use AJAX to send it to a server. Classes aren't sent to a server as part of a form, you'll need to write your own code that turns it into data to save it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this javascript. So if checkbox checked, it will add class colorify to tr

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if (this.checked)
    {
        $(this).parents("tr").addClass('colorify');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parents("tr").removeClass('colorify');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should solve your issues:

```
function updateRowColor() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').toggleClass('colorify', this.checked);
}

// Update on page load
$('input:checked').each(updateRowColor);

// Listen for change on the element
$('input').on('change', updateRowColor);
```